# Stolen iPhone 6 can't log out of iMessage

Tags: iphone

My iPhone 6 was stolen a week ago. I can't remove that phone number from my Apple account. It is still listed in iMessage, etc. The help file I see tells me I have to sign out of FaceTime and iMessage from my iPhone.  *I don't have my iPhone.*

How do I get rid of this phone number?  I have told Apple it's stolen; I've told my phone carrier too.  And yet...

Comment: Have you tried signing out of all devices connected to your Apple ID? I'm not sure if that will work or not but it's worth a shot. Go to [appleid.apple.com](http://appleid.apple.com) and sign in. Then scroll down to the devices section and if you see you're still signed into the stolen iPhone, sign out of it.

Comment: This is the strange thing. As soon as it was stolen, I went to appleid.apple.com and removed the phone. But on my computers, it still shows that phone number associated with imessage, and it won't take it off--it says I have to take that phone number off using the phone itself.

Comment: If that's the case then I'm not sure there is anything you can do on your end. You might try contacting Apple Support again and asking them if they can remove that phone number from iMessage for you. Even though you already contacted them and reported it stolen they might not have thought to do that. I would check back here too though in case someone does end up posting a solution for you. Hope you can get it resolved soon!